# Distribucion de pesos

Tags: r, excel, rstudio

Estoy llevando a cabo un proyecto de estadistica con Rstudio, en un paso del mismo tengo que calcular un peso y multiplicarlo por un valor para extraer un resultado tantas veces como variables relacionadas tenga. Es decir, en la columna GHG Emissions llevo a cabo el siguiente bucle:

```
col <- Variables$Indicador[1:5]
OUTPUT$`GHG Emissions...8` <- 0
for (i in seq_len(nrow(OUTPUT))) {
  ccode <- OUTPUT[i, 3]
  acode <- OUTPUT[i, 4]
  
  resultado <- 0
  
  peso1 <- buscarv(col[1], Variables$Indicador, Variables$`Peso - Variable`)
  valor1 <- buscars(ccode, acode, Modelling_1$Country_Code, Modelling_1$`Activity Code`, Modelling_1$`CO₂ emissions from fossil fuel combustion and cement production (tCO2/capita)`)
  if (!is.na(peso1) && !is.na(valor1)) {
    resultado <- resultado + peso1 * valor1
  }
  
  peso2 <- buscarv(col[2], Variables$Indicador, Variables$`Peso - Variable`)
  valor2 <- buscars(ccode, acode, Modelling_1$Country_Code, Modelling_1$`Activity Code`, Modelling_1$`Greenhouse Gas Emissions`)
  if (!is.na(peso2) && !is.na(valor2)) {
    resultado <- resultado + peso2 * valor2
  }
  
  peso3 <- buscarv(col[3], Variables$Indicador, Variables$`Peso - Variable`)
  valor3 <- buscars(ccode, acode, Modelling_1$Country_Code, Modelling_1$`Activity Code`, Modelling_1$`Millions of metric tones of CO2 equivalent`)
  if (!is.na(peso3) && !is.na(valor3)) {
    resultado <- resultado + peso3 * valor3
  }
  
  peso4 <- buscarv(col[4], Variables$Indicador, Variables$`Peso - Variable`)
  valor4 <- buscars(ccode, acode, Modelling_1$Country_Code, Modelling_1$`Activity Code`, Modelling_1$`Greenhouse gas emissions`)
  if (!is.na(peso4) && !is.na(valor4)) {
    resultado <- resultado + peso4 * valor4
  }
  
  peso5 <- buscarv(col[5], Variables$Indicador, Variables$`Peso - Variable`)
  valor5 <- buscars(ccode, acode, Data_SASB$`Country Code`, Data_SASB$`Activity Code`, Data_SASB$`GHG Emissions`)
  if (!is.na(peso5) && !is.na(valor5)) {
    resultado <- resultado + peso5 * valor5
  }
  
  input <- 0.2
  
  resultado <- resultado / input / 100
  
  OUTPUT$`GHG Emissions...8`[i] <- resultado
}
```

Este bucle es correcto y funciona bien, el problema es que no diferencia entre valores nulos (NA) y 0, unicamente tiene que si un valor es nulo se salta ese calculo. Ahi esta mi problema, necesito que los pesos se redistribuyan si esto ocurre, por ejemplo, si el peso 1 falla, este se distribuya en los otros 4, si falla otro, se distribuya en los 3 restantes, etc. He intentado hacerlo normalizando de 1-100 y convirtiendo los valores NA en ceros y usando esta formula: (v1*p1)/(v1*p1+v2*p2+v3*p3). Sin embargo, los valores no salen como deberian salir. ¿Qué podría hacer?

Comment: Bienvenido  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: El código y la explicación de tu pregunta me parece que no están alineados a tu problema fundamental que es la imputación de los valores NA.  ¿Por que no nos brindas un ejemplo de los datos y como quisieras que los NA se reimputen a un cierto valor?

Comment: No entiendo la etiqueta de Excel en esta publicación. Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)